# Magento 1.7.0.2 CE: jQuery conditional show <dd> if top element has specific class

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, jquery, bundle

We use bundle item.
Customer can make a combination of different sku's.
We group the sku' in logical sections (e.g. motor, color, wheels, ...).
Some groups are required to have at least one entry others not (e.g. accessory).

Initially all groups are toggled hidden for easier orientation.
After clicking "Add to cart" we show all groups with `jQuery('dd').show()` to enable the magento validation of the checkbox groups (required or not).

Question: We just want to show all groups (element `<dd>`) if the above label 
of `<dt>` has the class "required" or if easier use the `class="validate-one-required-by-name"` from the child input box within the `<li>` element. So the customer has the focus only on the required bundle groups he has to mark es checked.

**HTML Structure is:**

```
<dl>
 <dt>
  <label class="required">
 </dt>
 <dd>  <--- this i want to show if <label> class of above <dt> is "required".
  <div>
   <ul>
   <li><span><input class="...validate-one-required-by-name"></input></span></li>
   <li><span><input class="...validate-one-required-by-name"></input></span></li>
   <li><span><input class="...validate-one-required-by-name"></input></span></li>
  </div>
 </dd>
<dl>
```

[image]

How can I make the show of `<dd>` element dependent from the above `<dt> <label>` class `"required"` or from the child class of the `<input-box>` in the `<li>` list?

**Finally found the answer:**

```
jQuery('input').filter('.validate-one-required-by-name').closest('dd').show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer as found by OP.

Using `jQuery('input').filter('.validate-one-required-by-name').closest('dd').show();`